# Passing objects to layout in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm passing objects to the Layout from the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult MyProfile()
{
  var roles = new List<int?>();
  User.Roles.ForEach(r => roles.Add(r.ID));
  return View(new ProfileModel()
  {
    LoginUser = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.LastName) ? string.Empty : User.LastName.ToLower()),
    UserRole = new List<int?>(roles)
  });
}

public class ModelBase {

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string LoginUser { get; set; }

    public List<int?> UserRole { get; set; }

    public ModelBase() {
        UserRole = new List<int?>();
    }
}

 public class ProfileModel : ModelBase { }
```

This works but, I have to do this for all my Controller Action when returning a view because I need the roles and login user on all my views.

Is there a way for me to do this just once, without having to repeat it in my actions?

I try adding to it to a base controller, but ROLES and LOGINUSER were always null.

I know this has been addressed a lot on SO, but they are all doing the something.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to render details of the user and their roles in every view?

Comment: Yes, the roles is uses for populating the navigation.

Comment: A better approach would be to have a `[ChildActionOnly]` method that returns a partial view of your navigation html, and then in the layout, use `@Html.Action()` to call the method and render the partial view in your layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Stephen Muecke suggestion I did this:

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Navigation() {
        return PartialView("_Navigation", new LayoutModel(User));
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult LoginInfo() {
        return PartialView("_LoginInfo", new LoginInfoModel(User));
    }
```

And

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-area">
        @Html.Action("LoginInfo", "Home")
</div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 sidebox">
        <div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
            @Html.Action("Navigation", "Home")
        </div>
 </div>
```

Bernard's suggestion also works, but i prefer this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult MyProfile()
{
    var roles = new List<int?>();
    User.Roles.ForEach(r => roles.Add(r.ID));
    return View(new ProfileModel(User));
}
```

Model:

```
public class ModelBase 
{
    public ModelBase(User user) {
        UserRole = new List<int?>();
        LoginUser =  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName) ? string.Empty : user.LastName.ToLower()),
    }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string LoginUser { get; set; }

    public List<int?> UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

ProfileModel:

```
public class ProfileModel : ModelBase 
{ 
    public ProfileModel(User user) : base(user) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a bad practice to write some code in your layout. If it is a razor view or something similar you can add user name and its roles directly in the view.